# showing random users while excluding copies of the same user

Tags: django

I'm trying to display 3 random users on my home page. How would I go about doing that? I can get the users to display, but sometimes there are two of the same user that are showing. I want to make sure every time there are 3 unique users showing.

**views.py**

```
def home(request):

    random_profile1 = (Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).order_by('?')[0])
    random_profile2 = (Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).order_by('?')[0])
    random_profile3 = (Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).order_by('?')[0])
    context = dict(random_profile1 = random_profile1, random_profile2 = random_profile2, random_profile3 = random_profile3)

    return render(request, 'dating_app/home.html',context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def home(request):

    context = {'random_profiles': Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).order_by('?')[:3]}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/home.html', context)
```

That'll give you an iterable which you can iterate over in your template.

```
{% for profile in random_profiles %}
    {{ profile }}
{% endfor %}
```